# ¿Por qué utilizar interfaces?

Tags: java, interfaz

tengo una duda sobre el por qué del uso de las interfaces, hice el siguiente ejemplo. No sé si valdrá para ponerlo como ejemplo.

```
interface Jefe{
    
    double bonus(double bonus);
}

class Empleado {
    
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private double salary;
    
    
        public Empleado (String name,int age,double salary) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.salary = salary;
        }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}

    class Jefe_Ejemplo extends Empleado implements Jefe{

        
        public Jefe_Ejemplo(String name, int age, double salary) {
            super(name, age, salary);
            
        }


        @Override
        public double bonus(double bonus) {
            
            return bonus + super.getSalary() ;
        }
        
    }

public class ejemplo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        Jefe_Ejemplo obj1  = new Jefe_Ejemplo("Tom",18,30000);
            
            System.out.println( obj1.bonus(10000));
    }

}
```

La pregunta es por qué debería de crear una interfaz para poner el método de dar un bonus al Jefe, si lo
puedo crear en la clase del jefe ?.
En que caso se deben de crear las interfaces? Es que no entiendo si puedo crear los metodos en la clase, para que voy a crearlos en una interfaz.

Comment: ¿Haz investigado algo? En Java las interfaces se usan por ejemplo para resolver el problema de la *herencia múltiple* y para resolver problemas de abstracción. Ver por ejemplo: [*Interface in java with example programs*](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/java-interface/) o bien el artículo de la documentación oficial [*What Is an Interface*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) o bien [el tutorial de Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-interfaces).

Comment: Hola, si estuve revisando, pero no me queda claro por que utilizarlo. Una cuestión, también podría servir para utilizar una función que no tenga nada que ver con la clase en si, Es decir una funcion para ordenar un listado de jefes o algo parecido.

Comment: Tu pregunta parece basada en opiniones lo que generaría su cierre.

Comment: Pero entonces, lo que tú quieres es que te expliquemos la utilidad de las interfaces y cómo se suelen usar?

Answer (score 0):

Como ya te ha comentado un compañero, un interface se usa para solventar la ausencia de herencia múltiple en Java así como para favorecer la abstracción.

Para entendernos, **es una especie de **contrato**, un molde, que las clases que lo implementan tienen que cumplir.**

Tomando de referencia tu ejemplo, imagina que tienes la clase **Jefe** que hereda de **Empleado**. Como dices, podrías meter el método **Bonus** directamente dentro de la clase Jefe, ¿pero qué pasaría si, además de Jefe, tuvieras la clase **DirectorRRHH**(por poner un ejemplo)? ¿no sería un lío? ¿y si cada uno de ellos diera un Bonus a sus empleados de distinta forma? Usando **Bonus** como interface e implementarlo sobre **Jefe** y **DirectorRRHH** es la forma de decir a esas clases que tienen que ser capaces de dar un bonus y que lo deben aplicar a su manera. Es, a su vez, una forma de saber a golpe de vista que esas clases se tienen que comportar de cierta manera (abstracción).

Por otro lado, recuerda que una clase puede usar varios interfaces, lo que es de gran ayuda respecto a la ausencia de herencia múltiple.

Te aconsejaría investigar (libros, webs, ejemplos) hasta comprender bien los conceptos.

A mi manera, espero haberte podido ayudar.